# Proper Implementation of Texture Atlas

Tags: c++, opengl, texture2d

I'm currently working alongside a piece of software that generates game maps by taking several images and then tiling them into a game map. Right now I'm working with OpenGL to draw these maps. As you know, switching states in OpenGL and making multiple draw calls is costly. I've decided to implement a texture atlas system, which would allow me to draw the entire map in a single draw call with no state switching. However, I'm having a problem with implementing the texture atlas. Firstly, would it be better to store each TILE in the texture atlas, or the images themselves? Secondly, not all of the images are guaranteed to be square, or even powers of two. Do I pad them to the nearest power of two, a square, or both? Another thing that concerns me is that the images can get quite large, and I'm worried about exceeding the OpenGL size limitation for textures, which would force me to split the map up, ruining the entire concept.

Here's what I have so far, conceptually:

-Generate texture

-Bind texture

-Generate image large enough to hold textures (Take padding into account?)

-Sort textures?

-Upload subtexture to blank texture, store offsets

-Unbind texture

Comment: This is a very common problem, why not use available tools? I think NVIDIA provides some.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not so much a direct answer, but I can't really answer directly since you are asking many questions at once. I'll simply try to give you as much info as I can on the related subjects.

The following is a list of considerations for you, allowing you to rethink exactly what your priorities are and how you wish to execute them.

First of all, in my experience (!!), using texture arrays is much easier than using a texture atlas, and the performance is about equal. Texture arrays do exactly what you think they would do, you can sample them in shaders based on a variable name and an index, instead of just a name (ie: mytexarray[0]). One of the big drawbacks include having the same texture size for all textures in the array, advantages being: easy indexing of subtextures and binding in one draw call.

Second of all, always use powers of 2. I don't know if some recent systems allow for non-power of 2 textures totally without problems, but (again in my experience) it is best to use powers of 2 everywhere. One of the problems I had in a 500*500 texture was black lines when drawing textured quads, these black lines were exactly the size needed to pad to a nearest power of two (12 pixels on x and y). So OpenGL somewhat creates this problem for you even on recent hardware.

Third of all (is this even english?), concerning size. All your problems seem to handle images, textures. You might want to look at texturebuffers, they allow for large amounts of data to be streamed to your GC and are updated easier than textures (this allows for LOD map systems). This is mostly nice if you use textures but only need the data in them represented in their colors, not the colors directly.

Finally you might want to look at "texture splatting", this is a way to increase detail without increasing data. I don't know exactly what you are making so I don't know if you can use it, but it's easy and it's being used in the game industry alot. You create a set of textures (rock, sand, grass, etc) you use everywhere, and one big texture keeping track of which smaller texture is applied where.

I hope at least one of the things I wrote here will help you out,
Good luck!

PS: openGL texture size limitations depend on the graphics card of the user, so be careful with sizes greater than 2048*2048, even if your computer runs fine others might have serious issues. Safe values are anything upto 1024*1024.

PSS: excuse any grammer mistakes, ask for clarification if needed. Also, this is my first answer ever, excuse my lack of protocol.

Comment: Well, texture buffers (or buffer textures) are totally useless for common texturing purposes, since they don't allow normalized access, filtering or more than 1 dimension. They don't have anything to do with textures at all and are just a way to access a buffer object as a linear array (and thus a kind of *"shader storage buffers lite"*).

Comment: Christian Rau is correct. However my intention was to mention a use to buffer data without a texture, because the goal of the question of the thread is unclear to me.

Comment: I should have done more research on texture arrays; this appears to be exactly what I need. I'm assuming I should pad all the textures to the size of the largest texture (which I will pad to the NPO2)?

Comment: Yes, so I suggest keeping the individual sizes close to eachother, to reduce superfluous padded data. BTW: are you sure you can't order your map in fixed size pieces? It simplifies everything :)

Comment: What do you mean "fixed size pieces"?

Comment: I mean splitting your entire map into square pieces of equal size. This way all pieces are (for instance) 512*512 and you wouldn't have to worry about padding anything. It's no big deal, it just makes it easier for you.